# Netty client bootstrap

Tags: java, tcp, client, netty

I am developing an application where I have a set of external TCP servers, which I have to connect from within my application.

- I have a set of drivers which connect these servers.
- a tcp client creating and returning the connection.
- every driver communicates with an device, which is the tcp server

Now it is not clear to me what is the correct way to handle the client bootstrap. Should the TcpClient create a bootstrap and reuse it to open new channel or is it better to create a new Bootstrap every time a driver connects the device (server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would create a new `Bootstrap` per client (driver) and re-use it. The most important part in general is that you want to re-use the `EventLoopGroup` if possible. You may even share the same group with all the drivers if possible. This will ensure you can maximise the usage of the threads per `EventLoopGroup` and keep resource usage to a minimum.